# C# listen to notify property changed

Tags: c#, sql, azure, inotifypropertychanged

I’m creating a groceries app. I have an `ItemsController` that keeps the list of `Items` and handle database download/upload.

My `Items` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and my user interface updates as soon as I change some of their fields.

I would like to also be notified in the `ItemsController` when the user changes the status of an `Item` (like ticking it out of the shopping list) to be able to upload the change to the SQL database.

How can I hook to this property changed event?

---

The `Item` class looks like this:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int quantity;

    public int Quantity
    {
        // some fields look like this

        get { return quantity; }
        set
        {
            if (quantity != value)
            {
                this.quantity = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Quantity");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
```

The `Controller`:

```
public ItemsController
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> AllItemsFromDB;

    public void LoadAll()
    {
         // Connects to DB, download JSONs
         // create items from the JSON
         // and fills AllItemsFromDB

         // here I’d like to hook to property changed, 
         // and then call the update method
    }
}
```

I’m using Azure to keep my stuff in the SQL server, and Azure functions for the web API middleware.

Comment: You can add an edit function to the observablecollection that fires the event for you and changes the value of an item. and from there you dont edit the objectes directly instead you use your new function

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` is an interface used for data binding and updating the UI *mainly in WPF*. It has nothing to do with SQL Server or Azure. What are you *really* trying to do and why do you think `INotifyPropertyChanged` would help?

Comment: INPC is rarely used in web applications because there are no individual change events and no bound data objects on the server's side. Once the response is sent to the browser, any loaded objects are simply gone. Modifications are posted from the browser to the server explicitly, which means you already know which objects have changed and what changed from the contents of the POST request

Comment: Any MVC tutorial shows how to create a CRUD application. The [documentation site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#pivot=core) contains extensive [Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/getting-started/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows), `How To` guides and [courses](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/web). Check for example [Tutorial: Implement CRUD Functionality - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: diving there, thanks for the clue